# NodeJS REGEX: Efficient Regex Search for multiple keywords?

Tags: regex, node.js

I have a search now that iterates over each json object that I have and each keyword. I want to match this search exclusive, not inclusive and I'm guessing I will need more robust regex. Basically, test true if the string contains ALL of the keywords. (order does not matter)

Searching for "This Text" would **include the following results:**

"this text", "this is a text", "This Text", "Text This", "this is a long string and text", "a long string with this in the middle and text", "that this that this text"

**and negate text similar to the following strings:**

"that text", "this is not", "text that is not included"

Here's the script I have right now.

```
items.forEach(function(item) { //iterate over the items array
    var s = JSON.stringify(item); //convert each item in items to a string
    var matched = false;
    sarray.forEach(function(qs) { //take the toArray converted query and iterate over it
        var r = new RegExp(qs, "g"); //compose a regex object with the stringified query
        if(r.test(s)) { //if regex finds the keyword in the item string,
            matched = true; //set matched to true
        }
    });
    if(matched) {
        results.push(item); //push the item into the results array
    }
```

Comment: This is a _really_ slow way to do this. JSON.stringify and then using regex is pretty slow here. Flatten the item first to an object or better, a `Map` (rather than stringifying) and then use fast map lookup on each of the items. There are much faster ways than that too.

Comment: I've already tested performance, it exceeds expectations at <1ms/query. I just need an exclusive search, not inclusive.

Comment: Ew... well, as you wish `sarray.reduce(function(accum,cur){ return accum && r.test(new RegExp(qs,"g")) }` - See [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - this is what you want instead of a `.forEach` :)

Comment: You gave me the same regex. Say I search for "This Text". That regex expression will look for "This Text" and will test negative on "This is Text". Which is *not* what I want. Furthermore, what I have now will include "That Text" and "This That" in results, which is not preferred.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't very clear from the question, you might want to edit that example in :) What about `"This This Text"` and `"This is the Text"` and `"This text"` ?

Comment: Yeah, I would want to include those. The goal here is to stringify each object and test against the keywords. So if the object was {"title":"This text", "location":"Austin, TX"}, I should be able to search "text austin, tx" and receive a TRUE on that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a simple function instead of regular expression because in this case, a complex regex would be needed.

```
/**
 *
 * Look for all `items' inside `str'.
 *
 *@param str   the string to search inside
 *@param items all items that must appear in the string
 *
 *@return 
 *    TRUE  => All items were found
 *    FALSE => At least one item was not found
 */
function all_items_present(str, items) {
 var i;
 var len=items.length;
 var found=true;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if(str.search(items[i])==-1) {
            found=false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return found;
}

// returns true
all_items_present(
   '{"title":"This text is foo", "location":"Austin, TX(bar)", "baz":false}',
   ['foo','bar','baz']
);
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/7FwUP/1/

---

Here is the equivalent regex for finding `foo`, `bar` and `baz` in no particular order:

```
^.*?(?:foo.*?bar.*?baz|foo.*?baz.*?bar|baz.*?foo.*?bar|baz.*?bar.*?foo|bar.*?baz.*?foo|bar.*?foo.*?baz).*?$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: I never thought about making "match" a truthy value and then negating. I think I know what to do. Just changed matched var setter to true, and then checked for regex falsey value and then negated the match if I couldn't find all of the results. Awesome, thanks.